# Multi-line footer for single page

Tags: header-footer, copyright

I need to add a copyright notice to my paper, and do not want it to break the layout, so I want to place it into the footer/header area of the initial page. Text may be multi-line. It should be displayed on the first page *only*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyfoot[C]{Copyright \textcopyright\ This material is declared a work of the 
  U.S.~Government and is not subject to copyright protection in the United States. 
  Approved for public release; distribution is unlimited.}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Also, note that this suggestion hold for *all* pages defined as `plain`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a different approach and use the `eso-pic` package to place something globally on the first page

Comment: It was helpful, but I hacked a bit, and still there were warnings. What I've done: \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(54pt, 54pt){\begin{minipage}{505pt} %multiline_text% \\ \\ \\ anchor \end{minipage}}}. The text turned out to be vertically centered s.t. its center corresponded to the bottom border of the page, so I added an invisible anchor. Also, there were warnings: "! A <box> was supposed to be here.", "! Missing number, treated as zero", "! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)." twice. Thanks, anyway. :)